# Index was outside the bounds of the array, but i can't see the error

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

```
int n =Count("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA");; //return 6

TreeNode[] db_name = new TreeNode[n];
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("show databases", connection);
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    dataReader.Read();
    db_name[i] =  new TreeNode(dataReader[i].ToString());
}
```

Why do I get IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled,Index was outside the bounds of the array?
If the Count() funciont return 6 that means there are 6 rows so 6 fields [0][1][2][3][4][5]
I put a breakpoint in the for loop and I get the error at the second loop, when i=1.
How can I fix that? I can't see the error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the first line compile at all?

Comment: Your code is based on a wrong assumption that `show databases` command would return a single column for each row in `information_schema.SCHEMATA`. This assumption is incorrect - the `information_schema.SCHEMATA` has a row for each database schema, not for each column returned by `show databases`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `dataReader.Read()` advances to the next available record.

When you call `dataReader[i]`, you're probably trying to get a column that doesn't exist in your returned data. On the first iteration, `dataReader[i]` is trying to get the first column, but then on the second iteration it's just trying to get the second column, then third, etc. You're probably not returning 6 columns, so that's going to throw an exception.

You could try something like this instead, assuming that each record is just a string:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    dataReader.Read();
    db_name[i] =  new TreeNode(dataReader.GetString(0));

          // or use dataReader[0].ToString(), but don't change the index of 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.

```
int i=0;
if (dataReader.HasRows)
{
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        db_name[i] =  new TreeNode(dataReader.GetString(0));          
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Just because it isn't an array doesn't mean you can't access the data reader like one. If it didn't have the indexer the program wouldn't compile. MySqlDataReader probably implements [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which has array-like access to the columns.

Comment: @Drik Oh, I didn't know it. Thanks, Dirk